# Ios Launching Fgallery from UITableView in tabbed application

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, photo-gallery, tabbed-interface

I am trying to build a small app. It's a tabbed app with 3 tabs: photos, videos, documents
Each tab displays a tableview to select wich gallery, video, document is to be shown; Videos work fine.

I'm having trouble with photo galleries. I use **Fgallery** which is working fine from the sample: [Fgallery git](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone/tree/master/FGallery)

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FGalleryViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <FGalleryViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> { 
    NSArray *localCaptions;
    NSArray *localImages;
    NSArray *networkCaptions;
    NSArray *networkImages;
    FGalleryViewController *localGallery;
    FGalleryViewController *networkGallery;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

### .m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize myTableView;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect tableViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
                              initWithFrame:tableViewRect
                              style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.myTableView = tableView;   
    self.myTableView.autoresizingMask =
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
}
```

and

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
             NSLog( @"Choix Table");

    if( indexPath.row == 0 ) {
        NSLog( @"selection 1");

        localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:localGallery animated:YES];  
    }
    else if( indexPath.row == 1 ) {
        networkGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:networkGallery animated:YES];
    ...
}
```

I really don't know how to display the gallery. The `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is the one from **fgallery**, I tried to modify it to show the viewm but I'm new to Objective-C and I'm stuck.

Any help or guideline will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I tried to add `[self.view addSubview:localGallery.view];` with no effect. I do not understand the views concept...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FGalleryViewController.m, I added btn2 to the navigation controller

```
- (void)setUseThumbnailView:(BOOL)useThumbnailView
{
    _useThumbnailView = useThumbnailView;
    if( self.navigationController ) {
        if (_useThumbnailView) {
            UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"See All" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(handleSeeAllTouch:)] ;
            [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:btn animated:YES];
            UIBarButtonItem *btn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)] ;
            [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:btn2 animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

And voilà

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
if( indexPath.row == 0 ) {
        NSLog( @"selection 1");

        localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
// Create the navigation controller and present it modally.
        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                        initWithRootViewController:localGallery];
        [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

View shows ok now but I am missing the back button